# Decoding html encoded character in velocity liferay

Tags: liferay, decode, velocity, utf8-decode, liferay-velocity

As title, I have an encoded String that I got from my URL, I want to display to user but don't know how to decode it

T%E1%BB%87p t%E1%BA%A3i l%C3%AAn => Tệp tải lên

I'm using liferay 6.1 ga1, and try to create some webcontent template.

Comment: I wonder where you "have" this. If something is URL-encoded, typically it is just a regular, decoded string if you read it from the parameters of an HTTP request. Could you give some more hints on which parts you're talking about? Thanks

Comment: I got this file name from url that selected in document and media field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with httpUtil, that should be available in velocity context.

```
$httpUtil.decodeURL("T%E1%BB%87p t%E1%BA%A3i l%C3%AAn")
```

would get you `Tệp tải lên`